# DirectConsumerNotAvailableException when defining camel routes in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to create a simple spring boot app which takes list of routes and process it parallelly in routebuilder. I am using proceduretemplate to call my routes by defining my startroute: direct start. When i hit i am getting org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://start].Exchange.[]. I am unable to figure out the issue here.below is my code.

**TestController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/service")
@Component
public class TestController {
   @EndpointInject(uri = "direct:start")
   private ProducerTemplate template;
   @RequestMapping(value = "/test",method =RequestMethod.GET)

    public void getAccountDetails(){
       ArrayList<String> callList = new ArrayList<String>();
       callList.add("direct:phone");
       callList.add("direct:sms");
       callList.add("direct:email");
       template.sendBody(callList);
      }
```

**CamelRoute.java**

```
@Component
public class  CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

final String BASE_ROUTE = "direct:start";


   public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(BASE_ROUTE).recipientList(body()).setParallelProcessing(true);
    from("direct:phone").log("customer call made");

    from("direct:sms").log("phone call made");

    from("direct:email").log("email call made");

}
```

**version**
    camel-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.17.0'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like the Camel route is not started before your rest controller calls Camel. Also try upgrading Camel

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I´m running into the same, and I do not know what is going on. Camel seems to load my route as a "DirectComponent" but there aren´t any consumers.